# How to ensure that layout looks the same no matter what the screen size is

Tags: android

What is the proper way to ensure that the screens look similar in mdpi, hdpi, xdpi, xxdpi.

I know that I am supposed to use "dp", and use asset studio for images but when I run my app on the emulator for a hdpi it still looks like shit.

I  have researched a bit and found that I am supposed to make multiple layout folders? layout-small, layout-large, ect.

Also, I have found that I can make different dimension folders.

Here is some code from one of my activities:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.nordquistproductions.getcrazy_sociables.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:onClick="onButtonClick">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/AppName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textSize="65sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/playbutton"

    android:text="✓"
    android:textColor="#000011"
    android:textSize="40sp"

    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:shadowColor="#000011"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:layout_above="@+id/otherappsbutton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button

    android:id="@+id/otherappsbutton"
    android:text="Other\nDrinking\nApps"
    android:textColor="#000011"
    android:textSize="12sp"

    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sociables"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textSize="55sp"
    android:id="@+id/sociables"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Play"
    android:id="@+id/Playtext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/playbutton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:background="@drawable/penguinicon"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Which is the correct technique?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Ended up using different layout folders: layout-hdpi, layout-xhdpi. This way I could customize the size of my items appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a git library for android, which provides auto scalable dimensions
You can use it for your height and width of widgets which will auto resize the widgets/layouts based on the screen size

https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Support Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

Define looking like shit? Are your drawables pixalated? Views to big? You can do a lot with RelativeLayout and wrap_content when you can use them. 
I've found that [This](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) is a good utility to generate drawables and different assets so that they look good on different displays and densities.

Comment: Well basically my imageview gets in the way of the text view and the buttons I have are the same size in hdpi as they are in xdpi. The image still looks good.

Comment: What does your layout look like? If you set the image view or text to be a set width then it may overlap, you should set them to wrap_content

Comment: Just saw your layout, the imageview will stay centered regardless. Either set layout_above or below of the image view on the other layouts so they stay out of the imageview's way.

Comment: I used set width and heights. 200dpx200dp. when I change it to wrap content the image covers the whole screen

Comment: You can make the image smaller or whatever size you want..set width & height match parent & wrap content respectively later you can use padding to make image looks good not shit..try it

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is achievable with the following tags

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

If still with that you cannot see the screen always using the whole size of the screen

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

If you could provide screenshots of what exactly you want to achieve we could help you more.
Kind regards!